# How Make SearchBar Like Iphone Setting

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisearchbar

Hi Thanks For answers in advance I Have 2 Question First How to make search bar present like setting when nothing is searched yet the background shows the setting and second how is it from static tableview show the search result

```
   searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = self
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you have an empty UITableView, and you want to have a search bar when no search has been performed yet. Then, you want to have the search results appear in that table view.

First, I would suggest always having the search bar on top of the table view so that users can perform another search after the first one. But if that is not your goal, you could have the following:

```
var didPerformSearch: Bool = false
```

then, when the user performs the first search, set it to true. Then have :

```
if didPerformSearch == true {
   yourSearchBar.isHidden = true
}else{
   yourSearchBar.isHidden = false
}
```

Also, your results table view HAS to be dynamic, because the number of search results and the search results themselves will differ depending on the search.

So, use a dynamic table view and a `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableviewDataSource` or a `UITableViewController` to show your search results, which I can't show you how to do because I don't know how you get your search results.

Hope I helped!

**EDIT** :

Okay so after reading your comments I actually understand what you want to do. 
You could have a table view for search results on top of your `ViewController` with `resultsTableView.isHidden = true`.
Then, when the user taps the search bar, you would set `resultsTableView.isHidden = false`

OR

You could even animate it like this :
`UIView.animate(duration: 0.2) {
   resultsTableView.alpha = 1
}`

(set it to 1 to show it, to 0 to hide it)

Comment: actually I want to have a search bar in a viewcontroller (not uitableviewcontroller) and when i tap search bar and search show result in a table view

Comment: Or make a table view with static rows and when search happened it show result on dynamic tableview i think the solution for both of my question is one thing